# Non-integer order of Bessel's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, bessel-functions

I was introduced to Bessel's equation in class: $x^2 y'' + xy' + (x^2-p^2)y = 0$ where $p$ is a constant, not necessarily an integer. I want to ask what does $p$ in the Bessel function not being an integer, say complex number, possibly mean? It's hard to wrap my head around the idea that the order of Bessel Function can be a non-integer.

Comment: Do you remember when you went from $x!$ to $\Gamma(x+1)$ ? Same story (at least to me).

Comment: A close analogy is the ODE $\,x\,y' = p\,y.$ If $\,p\,$ is an integer, there is an obvious solution, but what if $\,p\,$ is not an integer?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Do you mind explaining how going from $x!$ to $\Gamma (x+1)$ is related to non-integer $p$ in the Bessel's equation? Also I would really appreciate it If you can write a separate answer, because getting an answer for a question on Stack Exchange is part of a class assignment for me this week.

Comment: @Somos Thank you for your suggestion! I haven't yet learned ODE in the complex domain, so I'm not sure about the technicalities of it, but I do want to get a brief intro and maybe an representation of this kind of ODE in other fields or in the real world. If you can write me a separate answer for my question, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The point is that the function $\,x^p\,$ is analytic everywhere (except for poles) if $\,p\,$ is an integer. If $\,p\,$ is **not** an integer, then you need to introduce branch cuts. The exact similar situation arises with Bessel functions.